# vba to unhide a column when opening a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

My user form has two buttons, one to unhide column A and another one to hide column A to give the user the option of seeing only the data they need and when they need. The code for this is below.

```
  Private Sub OptionButton3_Click()
  'Hide column A
  Worksheets("Page1").Columns("A:A").Hidden = True
  End Sub


  Private Sub OptionButton4_Click()
  'UnHide column A
  Worksheets("Page1").Columns("A:A").Hidden = False
  End Sub
```

However, I'd like column A to be visible (unhidden) by default every single time the user opens the workbook. For example even if the user saves the workbook with column A being hidden, I want that next time someone opens the same spreadsheet to have column A visible automatically by default. I'm not sure how to amend the vba above for that. Any help much appreciated? Thanks

Comment: Just include the `Worksheets("Page1").Columns("A:A").Hidden = False` code within the `Workbook_Open` event.  (Or, because the `Open` event is sometimes problematic due to firing before the workbook is completely open, perhaps include it in the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event.)

Comment: hi, so instead of OptionButton4_Click() to write Workbook_BeforeSave ? don't think my button will still work if i do that though. thanks

Comment: No, just add the code in `Workbook_BeforeSave` **as well** - so you will execute that line on your `OptionButton4_Click` and in your `Workbook_BeforeSave`.  (If it was more than just one line, I would recommend having just one subroutine called from the two places, but for one line it isn't worth it - just replicate the line.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `workbook_open` even within `ThisWorkbook`

[image]